# Can’t set color of vim

Tags: bash, vim, centos

I've asked same question to stackoverflow but It evaluated offtopic at stackoverflow.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667728/cant-set-color-of-vim?noredirect=1#comment36357524_23667728

If it isn't offtopic at here please help me?

I’ve tried to set color of vim for editing C program text file.

My .vimrc is below.

[.vimrc]

```
set nu
colorscheme delek
syntax on
```

And `delek.vim` file is as follwing list.

```
ls -la /usr/share/vim/vim72/colors
total 80
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root 4096 Jun 14  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root root 4096 Jun 14  2013 ..
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2476 Apr  5  2012 blue.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2990 Apr  5  2012 darkblue.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  548 Apr  5  2012 default.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2399 Apr  5  2012 delek.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2812 Apr  5  2012 desert.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1666 Apr  5  2012 elflord.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2476 Apr  5  2012 evening.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 3306 Apr  5  2012 koehler.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2460 Apr  5  2012 morning.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2006 Apr  5  2012 murphy.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1037 Apr  5  2012 pablo.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2673 Apr  5  2012 peachpuff.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2311 Apr  5  2012 README.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1239 Apr  5  2012 ron.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2720 Apr  5  2012 shine.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 2445 Apr  5  2012 slate.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1629 Apr  5  2012 torte.vim
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 1840 Apr  5  2012 zellner.vim
$
```

After setting, I re-login and edit C source.

But no words are colored while there is a line under words.

How can I set it?

Comment: Are no words colored, or are just words with a line under them not colored? What kind of line do you mean? The cursor?

Comment: No words colored including words with a line uder them.I cant describ what kind of line. For example,`#include <stdio.h>` or `int` has line under its text but `main(){}` or `if(){}`doesn't have line under its text.

Comment: If you've never seen color using this vim, I'm wondering if it even has syntax coloring built in. Execute the command `:version`. About four or five lines down it should say "Small version" or "Huge version" or something similar. What does yours say? I have no explanation for the lines.

Comment: `:version                                                                                      
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Apr  5 2012 10:17:30)
Included patches: 1-411
Modified by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Compiled by <bugzilla@redhat.com>
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):`

Comment: Actually I'd been able to use colored words and had believed I was using vi Editor not vim. I mean I hadn't had any knowledge of vim. So I think I haven’t changed any settings about vim intentionally.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm out of ideas. I even created a .vimrc like yours and edited a C source file. `#include` was in purple and `<stdio.h>` was in green. No lines.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat solved at stackoverflow.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667728/cant-set-color-of-vim/23671309?noredirect=1#23671309